# Why can't this python code create temporary table in sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, temp-tables

I have the following python code to create temporary table in sqlite3 database. I have tested that the sql code works fine by running the code in "DB Browser Sqlite". However, for some reason, the python code does not create the temporary table successfully. What is wrong with the code?

I am using python v3.6

```
import sqlite3

db_pathname = "db.sqlite3"
sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_pathname)
sqlite_cur = sqlite_conn.cursor()

sqlite_cur.execute('''
                    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE latest_info AS 
                    SELECT * from infos t                    
                    WHERE
                    t.date_p =
                    (SELECT MAX(date_p) from infos t1                    
                    WHERE t1.info_id = t.info_id
                    )
                   '''
                   )

sqlite_conn.commit()
sqlite_conn.close()
```

Comment: How do you test if the table was successfully created? A temporary table will not be persisted after closing the connection...

Comment: I used the software `DB Browser for SQLite`. I copied and pasted the SQL code and run it in this software. I could see that the temporary table was created successfully. I didn't know temporary table will disappear after closing the connection. How do I get the temporary table to persist?

Comment: You create a normal table? `CREATE TABLE latest_info ...`?

Comment: Temporary table is just meant for a session, so that  you can for example do a join. as @Torxed said, the moment you close the session, the table is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table is disapearing after you close the connection because of the temporary keyword between create and table.

Try removing it and the table will be persisted.

Something like this

```
import sqlite3

db_pathname = "db.sqlite3"
sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_pathname)
sqlite_cur = sqlite_conn.cursor()

sqlite_cur.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE latest_info AS <-- there, no more TEMPORARY
                SELECT * from infos t                    
                WHERE
                t.date_p =
                (SELECT MAX(date_p) from infos t1                    
                WHERE t1.info_id = t.info_id
                )
               '''
               )

sqlite_conn.commit()
sqlite_conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I should not use temporary table if I want the table to persist in the first place. I am wondering why would people want to use temporary tables if they don't persist. Would you happen to know?

Comment: I guess this could be used as a holder for temporary result like if you where in a shell and refining the result one criteria after another. Or for reorganizing data between two complicated requests... Honestly never used it.

Comment: Thanks. I think the purpose is to write sql code which is more readable using temporary tables

Comment: Another reason is to avoid nested queries to improve performances.